# How to integrate the SMB Core Protocol into your own application?

Tags: c, qt, ntfs

I am developing software that integrates folder redirection, and my application may run in a complex network environment with one or more gateways, proxies, and NAT devices in between.

My application already communicates with a proxy server and establishes TCP/TDP socket connections, and I do not want to expand to additional socket connections.

1. I have already implemented folder redirection on Windows and Linux using WinFsp and fuse2 respectively, but my interface implementation may not be robust enough, and I may not be able to perfect this feature in the short or long term.
2. Therefore, I am considering integrating the functionality related to folder redirection protocol in SMB directly into my application and extending a message channel for the SMB protocol from my socket.
3. And I don't want to install an SMB server on the Linux server side. I need to integrate the SMB client and SMB server separately into my client and server, and start the file redirection service myself.

If you have any methods or suggestions, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitively read these:

- [Implementing CIFS](http://www.ubiqx.org/cifs/)
- [The samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Developer_Documentation#Source_code)
- [The source code itself](https://github.com/samba-team/samba)

You will find lots of info on how CIFS/SAMBA protocol works, how packets are formed and finally you have the source code to take w/e you need from it.

Good luck!